# How to simulate pairs from a joint distribution

Tags: stata, scatter-plot

I have two normal distributions X and Y and with a given covariance between them and variances for both X and Y, I want to simulate (say 200 points) of pairs of points from the joint distribution, but I can't seem to find a command/way to do this.  I want to eventually plot these points in a scatter plot.

so far, I have

```
set obs 100
set seed 1

gen y = 64*rnormal(1, 5/64)
gen x = 64*rnromal(1, 5/64)
matrix D = (1, .5 | .5, 1)

drawnorm x, y, cov(D)
```

but this makes an error saying that `x` and `y` already exist.

Also, once I have a sample, how would I plot the `drawnorm` output as a scatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related approach for generating correlated data is to use the `corr2data` command:

```
clear

set obs 100
set seed 1

matrix D = (1, .5 \ .5, 1)

drawnorm x1 y1, cov(D)
corr2data x2 y2, cov(D)


. summarize x*

Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      x1 |        100    .0630304    1.036762  -2.808194   2.280756
      x2 |        100    1.83e-09           1  -2.332422   2.238905

. summarize y*

Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      y1 |        100   -.0767662    .9529448  -2.046532   2.726873
      y2 |        100    3.40e-09           1  -2.492884   2.797518
```

**It is important to note that unlike `drawnorm`, the `corr2data` approach does not generate data that is a sample from an underlying population.**

---

You can then create a `scatter` plot as follows:

```
scatter x1 y1
```

Or to compare the two approaches in a single graph:

```
twoway scatter x1 y1 || scatter x2 y2
```

---

**EDIT:**

For specific means and variances you need to specify the mean vector `μ` and covariance matrix `Σ` in `drawnorm`. For example, to draw two random variables that are jointly normally distributed with means of 8 and 12, and variances 5 and 8 respectively, you type:

```
matrix mu = (8, 12)
scalar cov = 0.4 * sqrt(5 * 8) // assuming a correlation of 0.4
matrix sigma = (5, cov \ cov, 8)

drawnorm double x y, means(mu) cov(sigma)
```

The `mean` and `cov` options of `drawnorm` are both documented in the `help` file.

Comment: Thanks!  But I need x1 and y1 to have mean and variance as specified above.  How do I do that?

Comment: You just use the relevant values in `drawnorm`. Type `help drawnorm` for full syntax.

Comment: See my edit for a specific example. It can't get more clear/easy than that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an almost minimal example:

```
. clear 

. set obs 100
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 100

. set seed 1

. matrix D = (1, .5 \ .5, 1)

. drawnorm x y, cov(D)
```

As the `help` for `drawnorm` explains, you must supply *new* variable names. As `x` and `y` already exist, `drawnorm` threw you out. You also had a superfluous comma that would have triggered a syntax error.

`help scatter` tells you about scatter plots.